# Handling Non-User data in Rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

We have a ton of non-user data: 500 product types that haven't changed in 20 years, 200GB of geospatial data that never changes (Queens is always 40.73N/73.82W)... etc.  It's the same in Development and Production.  It should be the same in Test, but the during testing Rails empties *all* of the test tables, and it takes a ton of time to re-populate during testing.

What is the Rails way to partition this non-user data so that it doesn't have to be repopulated in Test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for this is found in the [Fixtures class.](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/Fixtures.html) (Search for "Transactional fixtures" on that page.)

The example they give starts out like this:

```
class FooTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    self.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    self.use_instantiated_fixtures = false
    ...
```

One of the projects I work on uses a test database with zero fixtures, so we just define this globally in test_helper.rb.

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  self.use_instantiated_fixtures  = false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

jdl shows you the settings to use for enabling and disabling transactional_fixtures, you should be able to set:

```
# Use self in ActiveSupport::TestCase if you don't have a config block
# in test/test_helper.rb
#
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

And stop Rails from trying to load fixtures before each run of your tests.  The downside is you can't assume all your fixtures are loaded into the DB.

**Real Answer**

**You have too much data in your fixtures.**  The Railsy thing to do it load **only the necessary data** in test fixtures; You do not need 200G of geospatial data (what freaking dataset is that anyway? that sounds way too big), and you probably don't need all 500 products.

**Tests are for your code**, so only include the few geospatial points you need for a test, or only include a few products with unique properties.  Keep the DB light enough to be loaded quickly.

Your test fixtures should be separate from you application bootstrapping data, take advantage of that.

***Real* Real Answer**

**Don't touch the database in your tests** (or, touch it very little).  The database is slow and fixtures are difficult or impossible to maintain well.  Instead, try using a **stubbing** framework like [Mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/) or [flexmock](http://flexmock.rubyforge.org/).  It's faster, and makes your tests read in a clearer manner.  Tests are for code, you can stub the database out of the situation and trust that ActiveRecord works (because...it's tested too! :-).

If you do choose to stick with fixtures, I recommend using [factory_girl](http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/tree/master) instead of the built in Rails fixtures.  You'll have a much better starting point.